# Текст из файла. <input type="file"/> в AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

Есть `input` с типом `file`. Пользователь выбирает файл. Потом есть кнопка. Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку (`ng-click`), запускается функция в контроллере.
Функция должна вытащить текст с этого файла. И вывести его (например в консоль. `console.log()`). Помогите сделать такое.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Приведите пожалуйста пример кода.

Comment: Пиши директиву.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. На чистом javascript код выглядит примерно так: https://jsfiddle.net/47bb9tcb/1/

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');

var input = document.getElementById('file');

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var files = e.target.files; // список файлов
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var type = file.type;
      // проверяем тип файла
      if (/text\/.*/.test(file.type)) {
        readFile(file, function(text) {
          result.innerText = text;
        });
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert('Ваш браузер не поддерживает FileAPI!');
  }
}, false);

function readFile(file, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = e.target.result;
    text = text.replace(/↵/g, '\n');
    callback && callback(text);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<div id="result"></div>
```